# iPhone Background App in Ad-hoc distribution?

Tags: ios, iphone, background, iphone-privateapi

I need to be able to ensure that the Pphone is always connected to a network. If it loses reception I need to be able to warn the user. Since the only way I see this working is using a background process is it possible to use private APIs so that the app can run in the background.

I know it can be done with Jailbroken phones but I would rather not Jailbreak the phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean having this behavior while running an app; check out the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) sample.

If you mean having this behavior while not running an app; check out [Android](http://www.android.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to run a background process.

You can send notifications to the phone while it is connected to a network, but obviously there is no way to send a notification when it is disconnected.

Comment: Undocumented or documented we don't have the means.