# Running application in background

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to run my iPhone application in the background. Please suggest if there is any way to do this.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864604/iphone-app-run-on-background

Answer (score 7):

Applications developed using the iPhone SDK can only run in the [foreground](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/IPhoneOSOverview/IPhoneOSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH4-SW7) on the iPhone. Only Apples applications (iTunes, email, etc) can run in the background.

Consider using [Push notification](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/apns.html) to update the application icon or display a message to the user if you want to do something when the user is not running your application.

Comment: for displayng just message when my application not running ,how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Only some of the Apple apps are allowed to do this.  It's a platform restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it with applications released for jailbroken iPhones, not those sold through the App Store. For example Backgrounder (available through Cydia) allows you to run any application as a background app:

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-backgrounder/wiki/Documentation