# How to make a service for iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to create a service for the iPhone which will run in the background.

I can't find any help anywhere and I dont know if its possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS** doesn't allow developer to create background services like in Android.

Check the belwo SO post that clearly state **Only some of the Apple apps are allowed to do this**

[Running application in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006389/running-application-in-background)

Comment: Thanks buddy.Is there any way i can do this?
May be in jailbroken phones.

Comment: There is no way for the standard apple SDK program, but not sure about jailbreak phones.

Answer (score 1):

what kind of service are you programming ? 
Because Apple allows certain kinds of background tasks.
More info at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Actually i want to capture screen all the time and save it to the photo album. Tried many things but nothing worked. I guess Apple sdk dont allow to run these kind of applications in background.

Comment: at what frequency do you want to take the screenshots ? if it's one every minute, maybe local notifications can do the trick but if you want to make a movie, i can't see any way.

Comment: I want to take scrennshot every second.I made an application which does it but when i am trying to take it to background,it stops.I  guess apple doesnt even allow to run our application in the background.What to do??