# how to run application in background in iphone?

Tags: iphone

i have implemented one application.I want to run this application in iphone background(not client server base).How it possible.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can not. But you can 'push' alerts.

Comment: You can only run the Flash Player in the background, sadly.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864604/iphone-app-run-on-background , among many others.

Answer (score 3):

Can't without jailbreaking. Apple does not let you run apps in the background. You can use Push Notifications to accomplish a lot of use cases for background programming, but the simple fact is you can't have a background process.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. See http://gizmodo.com/5256821/rumor-apple-considering-iphone-background-apps

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't let third party applications run in the background.  I do hope they change that feature soon!

Answer (score 0):

You can register your app to use gps/voip services and it will run in background!
One thing to be noted is such apps will be rejected from appstore unless there is really gps needed within the app for navigation.