# Can anyone demonstrate how to create an app for iPhone that runs in the background?

Tags: ios4, multitasking

I'd like to know if it is technically possible to create an app on iPhone that runs in the background, be it piggybacking while an audio is playing or GPS, VOIP, etc or using a third party API. I was able to create one using audio playback. Now I am looking for other possibilities. I know this will not be approved in app store, but I just want to know whether it is just a appstore approval issue and not a technical issue. Thanks.

Comment: See [
iphone app run on background?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864604/iphone-app-run-on-background).

Answer (score 0):

You just want confirmation right?
Well then yes it is possible and yes it is legal. As long as you follow the apple guidelines. For iOS 4 obviously. If it's for iOS 3 then you're going to have to use 3rd party applications and it does get very messy and yes your app will definitely get rejected.

Other than that hope that helped

**PK**

Comment: You don't have to follow Apple's guidelines to legally distribute an iPhone application.  See the [Library of Congress](http://www.copyright.gov/1201/) regulations.

Comment: What I meant by "legally" was in reference to the approval process for app store. Sorry, my bad. I was just looking for a technical proof-of-concept regardless of whether or not it will be approved in app store.

Comment: I was able to create an application by piggybacking an audio playback to allow my app to run in the background. I am looking for the possibility not to use piggybacking or Backgrounder app (for jailbroken phones). It should be stand alone.

Comment: can you please rewrite your question. As in the question you have written be it piggbacking and now youre saying not to use piggybacking. please do this as it will make your question a lot more clearer. thanks. It will also be less confusing.